# Battleship AI Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, probability

The figures in the *walkthrough* portion of [this](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/december32011/) article detail the algorithm fairly well.

I've developed the following short program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr['K' - 'A'][10 - 0] = {0};
    int largestShip;

    //grid
    cout << "   ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << (i + 1) % 10;
    }
    cout << endl << "  ____________" << endl;;

    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'K'; c++) {
        cout << c << " |";
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << arr[c - 'A'][i];
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //endgrid

    //heatmap
    largestShip = 5;
    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'K'; c++) {
        for(int i = 0; (i + largestShip - 1) < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < largestShip; j++) {
                arr[c - 'A'][j + i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(char c = 'A'; (c + largestShip - 1) < 'K'; c++) {
        for(int i = 0; i  < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < largestShip; j++) {
                arr[c - 'A' + j][i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    //endheatmap

    //showheatmap
    cout << "   ";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << (i + 1) % 10;
    }
    cout << endl << "  ____________" << endl;;

    for(char c = 'A'; c < 'K'; c++) {
        cout << c << " |";
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << arr[c - 'A'][i] % 10;
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    //endshowheatmap

    return 0;
}
```

It sets the initial probability of the squares whose precedence is set by the size of its corresponding integer values in the array of values.

However, I'm not very well versed in probability theory, and am uncertain how to approach and understand the necessary methods for manipulating the probability of the squares (and by association, their values) in order to accurately assign the probability at any given square after some shot is taken at that square.

An explanation of the effects of a shot on the probability values of the squares within the grid would be helpful.

Comment: The heatmap is the sum of the positions of all possible ships on the board.  (Probably not with their collisions accounted for) When you shoot and miss, certain ships are eliminated from being possible.  So the aircraft carrier of length 5 in up to 10 positions goes away (plus other ships).  Some of those possible ships may already have been eliminated, so don't double count.  The rules for when you hit are going to be different: figuring out what ship you hit (and sunk) will permit you to eliminate the possible other locations of that ship.

Comment: @Yakk I feel like I follow, somewhat.